# Docker-compose not show logs

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm runing my api of express and mongo with docker-compose using the command docker-compose up, all fine but when i try show the logs have the next output error:
[image]

Comment: That seems to be a PNG file, not an error message.  Can you edit the question to include the actual command you're running, the actual error you're getting, and the application code necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @DavidMaze Please notice, the command is clearly visible in the PNG, it was `docker ps` and then `docker-compose logs -f backend_api_1`, they are at the end of the red lines he made to hide irrelevant/private stuff. Below the logs command, the error is visible.

Comment: This is a common point of confusion with people about Docker and Docker-compose.  In general docker-compose works with services, not containers.  See @DennisvandeHoef's answer.  Note the manual page for the command `Usage: logs [options] [SERVICE...]`  The command needs a service name, not the name of a container.

Comment: thanks a lot the problem was that I hadn't named it and I was using the one I got from docker-compose output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common confusion point with docker-compose orchestration.  Docker compose deals with services, which then can start one or more containers for a service.
You can clarify this for yourself by looking at the manual page for whatever command you plan to use, as it will tell you whether it requires a service name or a container name.

For [docker-compose logs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/logs/) the manual shows:

> Usage: logs [options] [SERVICE...]

Since we don't have your docker-compose.yaml to refer to, we can only infer that you may have named the service backend_api.  I'm just repeating the answer provided by Dennis van de Hoef, which is a reasonable guess based on how docker will name containers for you.

```
docker-compose logs -f backend_api
```

The [docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/logs/) command can be used to look at the logs of a container.

```
docker logs -f backend_api_1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, i set a name for the container and all works

Answer (score 4):

With docker-compose logs you need to use the name of the service in the docker-compose.yaml not the name of the container.

You ran `docker-compose logs -f backend_api_1`, which is the name of the container. If your docker-compose file does not contain any special renaming, the following should work: `docker-compose logs -f backend_api` (assuming the service is called backend_api)

Comment: Thanks a lot bro!